# How do I install Java 6 on Mac OSX 14.3.1 when I already have other versions of Java installed?

Tags: java, macos, macos-sonoma

I need to install Java 6 on a Mac running OSX 14.3.1 (Sonoma) for one work project.

Oracle doesn't have a Java 6 download for Mac.

The Apple Support installer won't install Java 6 if I have other versions of Java installed (I have 11, 13 and 17).

I don't want to uninstall the other versions of Java, I will need them for parallel work projects.

I suppose I can move / delete / uninstall the newer versions, install Java 6, and then reinstall / move back the newer versions, but I have concerns that this may fail.

Has anyone managed to do this? What worked for you?

Comment: You could install another macOS in a virtual machine (Parallels, VirtualBox, etc.).

Comment: Java 6 is **really** old. Maybe try [apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US). But as I mentioned, it's **old**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use **Cast** feature:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew cask install java6
```

Or from *Captain Chaos* comment:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install java6
```

This will install **Java 6** on your system without interfering with the other Java versions.

Note that to manage your Java version configurations appropriately using tools like `java_home` or setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Yes, this worked, that got it installed, with one minor tweak:
'brew install java6' instead of 'brew cask install java6' Thank you!